# Edit xml file's DefaultValue using powershell script

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, windows-scripting

I want to edit the DefaultValue for the Property name = "UseThis" using PowerShell script.

Xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigFile xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" IsOverride="false">
  <Section Name="ClientConfiguration" Type="Repository.Config.Configuration">
    <Property Name="Base">
      <DefaultValue>https://app.net:190</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="Subject">
      <DefaultValue>Box</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="ApiVersion">
      <DefaultValue>2017-06-15</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="UseThis">
      <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="Configuration">
      <DefaultValue>ServiceConfiguration</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
  </Section>
 <Section Name="ClientConfiguration1" Type="Repository.Config.Configuration1">
    <Property Name="Base">
      <DefaultValue>https://app.net:1900</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="Subject">
      <DefaultValue>Box</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="ApiVersion">
      <DefaultValue>2011-08-15</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="UseThis">
      <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="Configuration">
      <DefaultValue>ServiceConfiguration</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
  </Section>
</ConfigFile>


   
$path = "filepath"
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load($path)

$nodes =  $xml.SelectNodes("/Section/Property")
foreach($Property in $nodes)
{
    switch($Property.name)
    {
        "UseThis" 
        {
            $property.DefaultValue.Value ="True"
            $configuration.save('filepath')
        }
    }
}
```

The above script is not working as no value is printed for the $nodes. I am very new to powershell and any help would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide valid XML that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @zett42 I have edited the xml file, could you please check this once?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the XML, but it looks like you have accidentally removed the PowerShell code.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the powershell code.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `.SelectNodes("/ConfigFile/Section/Property")` and `$property.DefaultValue ="True"`?

Comment: `$xml.save("$pwd\$path")`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like simple coding errors.  "/ConfigFile" was missing, and ".Value" shouldn't be there.  $configuration should be $xml.  It's good to have the full path for these .net methods.  They get confused about the current directory.

```
$path = "file.xml"
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("$pwd\$path")

$nodes =  $xml.SelectNodes("/ConfigFile/Section/Property")
foreach($Property in $nodes)
{
    switch($Property.name)
    {
        "UseThis" 
        {
            $property.DefaultValue ="True"
            $xml.save("$pwd\$path")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @js2010, this was very helpful!
The below code worked for me : 
$path = "filepath"
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("$path")

$nodes =  $xml.SelectNodes("/ConfigFile/Section/Property")
foreach($Property in $nodes)
{
    switch($Property.name)
    {
        "UseThis" 
        {
            $property.DefaultValue ="True"
            $xml.save("$path")
        }
    }
}

If I try to add $pwd then I get this error : Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."

Comment: Inside double quotes like I've done it?

Comment: Yes the same way.